# how to return to certain part of the program? java

Tags: java

I have a program that its supposed to display a menu take a number from the user to select from the menu do what its supposed to do and then return to the menu and I don't know how can I return to the menu?

Here is my code:

```
public class tst {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select");
        int slct = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("1.optionone");
        System.out.println("2.optiontwo");
        System.out.println("1.optionthree");
        switch (slct){
            case 1:System.out.println("you have selected optionone");// and then its suposed to go back to the menu
            case 2:System.out.println("you have selected optiontwo");// and then its suposed to go back to the menu
            case 3:System.out.println("you have selected optionthree");// and then its suposed to go back to the menu
        }        
    }        
}
```

the question its How can i make so after it print you have selected x option i returns to the menu again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while` loop. This allows you to loop back to the beginning of your loop after reaching the end.

**EDIT**: Java has no `goto` statement. However, if you ever decide to learn a new language (such as C) that *does* have `goto`, **don't** use it.

<s>Whatever you do, ***don't*** use `goto`. It's</s> `goto` is considered extremely bad practice and has become subject to [absurd humor](http://www.xkcd.com/292/).

Example:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing){
    //print out the options
    int slct = reader.nextInt(); //get input
    switch(slct){
        case 1:
            //user inputted 1
            break; //otherwise you will fall through to the other cases
        case 2:
            //...
            break;
        case 3:
            //...
            break;
        case 4: //or other number to quit, otherwise this will repeat forever
            keepGoing = false; //stop the loop from repeating again
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped me !

Comment: Except Java doesn't allow `goto`. So as cute as [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/292/) is, it is not bad practice to use `goto` in Java; it is a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can take design your menu using do while loop. You can re design your menu look like :

```
int slct = 0;

do {
  System.out.println("1.optionone");
  System.out.println("2.optiontwo");
  System.out.println("3.optionthree");
  System.out.println("4.Quit");
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Select");
  slct = reader.nextInt(); //get input

  switch(slct){
  case 1:
    //user inputted 1
    break; //otherwise you will fall through to the other cases
  case 2:
    //...
    break;
  case 3:
    //...
    break;
  }


} while(slct != 4);
```

When user enter 4 option then it will break the loop. Means do while loop will break using 4 input.

Comment: ? i dont understand you answer i dont need a quit option what i need its that after i select an option and the statement asociated with that option its executed  it returns to the menu